# View top week/month questions on pages I am not logged in

Tags: support, navigation

On Stack Exchange sites where I am not logged in, I see the header saying "How it works" and a list of questions saying "Explore our questions".

On sites where I am logged in, these disappears and there are tabs to switch between "active", "hot", "week" and "month" questions.

How can I view them on sites where I am not logged in?

I want to do this because I find it interesting reading the top questions of a week/month of a site, but do not want to log in for that.